# check if is the last child - dynamically created element

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to know if an element is the last child, these elements (anchors that can be selected) are dinamically created.
i'm using the following code:

```
$("button#linetime").on("click", function(){
   $("section#timelineSection").toggle();
   if ($("a.selected").is(":last-child") ){
      $("a.next").click();
   }
});
```

i need this function to translate in the right position the timeline so i can't catch it with `on("click", ".class", function() .. "`

there is a way to reach this?  or maybe to get the index ?

**EDIT**

```
<section class="cd-horizontal-timeline loaded" id="timelineSection">
   <div class="timeline">
      <div class="events-wrapper">
         <div class="events" style="width: 300px; transform: translatex(-120px);">
            <ol>
               <li><a href="url" ></a> </li>
               <li><a href="url" ></a> </li>
               <li><a class="selected" href="url" ></a> </li>
            </ol>
            <span class="filling-line" aria-hidden="true"></span> </div>
        </div>
       <ul class="cd-timeline-navigation">
          <li> 
             <a class="prev" href="#0">Prev</a>
          </li>
          <li> 
             <a class="next" href="#0">Next</a>
          </li>
          <button id="closeTimeline" type="button">Chiudi</button>
       </ul>
   </div>
</section>
```

but inside `<ol>` the elements are dinamically created

as you can see in the image bellow, the anchor with the selected class is green, but when i open the Timeline it is placed on the left and the IF serves to check if it is the last child to center it, but i can't reach it, cause it retourn every time true, even if it is the first element

[Timeline photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DmzP.png)

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) We need to see your DOM structure in order to help. `$("a.selected")` will match **all** elements matching that selector. If the first one is the last child in its parent that `is` call will return `true` (which may or may not be what you want). You may be looking for `is(":last")`, but again, we need more information to go on.

Comment: hi, thanks for comment, really i had only one `a.selected` in all the DOM, but yes i will put the structure of the linetime that could help a little more

Comment: I'm afraid it's still not clear what you're asking. If there's only going to be one of them, what's the `if` for? The fact of where it is isn't going to vary, so...?

Comment: i added a little explanation, it's just that i need to check if it is the last child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo could do something like this(check if parent "li" is the last one):

```
if (!$("a.selected").parent().next().length){
    $("a.next").click();
}
```